# how to delete a ingress controller on kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster in which I have multiple ingress controllers. I have deleted the source file of one ingress controller. How can I delete the ingress controller that I don't want further ??

Comment: Do you want to remove Ingress Controller (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) or Ingress resource, since you mentioned about source file, and I think it maybe yaml file? If you indeed want to remove Ingress Controller, so it depends how you installed it.

Answer (score 44):

first of all, you can follow below steps  without manifest files:

1. get the namespace which your ingress controller installed in

```sh
   kubectl get ns
```

for example : ingress-nginx

2- remove all resources in this namespace

```sh
kubectl delete all  --all -n ingress-nginx
```

if your ingress controller is not installed in a dedicated namespace so you will have to remove resources one by one .

```sh
kubectl delete ingress ingress-nginx
kubectl delete deployment ingress-nginx
kubectl delete service ingress-nginx
```

Comment: The ingress-nginx deployment YML's are quite large, are you sure everything they do is restricted to the namespace? (ie. does this really remove the whole thing?)

Comment: that was bad advice.. to remove everything

Comment: This is a bad advice, for me I started facing an 

Error from server (InternalError): error when creating ".\\sample.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://<url>.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": service "ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission" not found

Answer (score 5):

Deleting ingress doesn't just resolve to deleting the service, deployments. We need to delete the webhooks and Custom Resources that the ingressController has created. This way, you would be able to install another ingressController in a seemlessway, else you would resource already exists exception like I did.

Hence, Adding few points to what Sameh Ammar said, 
Get the namespace of the ingress you want to delete

```
kubectl get ns
```

Delete the namespace as a whole

```
kubectl delete all  --all -n ingress-nginx
```

Check and delete ingressClass

```
kubectl delete ingressClass nginx
```

You can fetch all ingressClass using

```
kubectl get ingressClass -A
```

Check and delete validating webhook,

```
kubectl delete ValidatingWebhookConfiguration ingress-nginx-admission
```

> (For my case)

You can fetch all the validating webhooks using

```
kubectl get ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
```

This should let you install and work on new ingress-controllers like a charm.